How can I extract the individual exposures of an Fujifilm X-T4 raw file that was shot in HDR mode
To my understanding, using the HDR mode of the X-T4 (and probably other Fujifilm cameras as well), results in multiple exposures taken, which are bundled in one big raw file.
When opening that file in a normal raw processor, you will only see one of these exposures, however, it should be possible to extract the others so that I can merge them with the HDR software of my choice.
I remember that I saw some commands for extracting them in some forum at some point but cannot find it anymore (all I find are links to some online service which doesn't seem to be reachable anymore).  So, how would I do that?
I'm on Linux, so need solutions that work there, but answers for other OSes are welcome as well, as they might be useful for other readers.

Have you check about other images on SD card? In other cameras camera make 3, 5 photos, combine them in one big image (HDR) and also can keep the source files

@RomeoNinov That's basically what Fujifilm does as well, just that the three exposures are bundled in one big raw file, instead of saving to separate files.

There is a website that will separate the three raw images from the single combined file.
https://www.solentsystems.com/
Select the HDR extract option at the top of the home page; you will get results like this.

If you want to know more about it or contact the person who wrote the script/made the website, that information is on the original fuji-x forum

Thanks! I found this website earlier via google but it didn't load, so I assumed it was dead.  Now it's working, so probably was just temporarily down.

While this works, I'd still prefer some tool that I can run offline.  But I'll read through the forum discussion when I have a bit more time, maybe necessary information can be found there.

[Edit : Sounds like the article I quoted missed a point and the .RAF that's saved is a container for the three sensor reads. Whether this means it should still be called a RAW file is a question for debate that I'll just drop here and retire to a safe distance.]

According to this, the short answer seems to be that you can't.

The three shots are not saved individually, only the final JPG is.
However if you shoot RAW+JPG, a single RAW file is saved to the SD
card alongside the “HDR” JPG file. The RAW file has the same exposure
settings you set on the camera prior to releasing the shutter.

It looks like this will be the middle (initial) exposure of the three.
It makes sense (to me, at least) that only a RAW file from a sensor read could be saved - creating a "RAW" file post HDR processing would seem to go against what a RAW file is. It sounds possible to save all three of the sensor reads as RAW files, but it doesn't look like that's what these cameras do - though you could achieve a similar result (but without the processed HDR .jpg) by using bracketing and combining in editing software.

This article seems to be wrong (or at least missing information) in this regard.  The camera does indeed bundle the three exposures it takes in one raw file (as a result, the resulting file is also about 3 times bigger than a normal raw).

Is it three different exposures or three different "reads" of the same exposure (which would make a difference when shooting moving subjects)

It's really different exposures.  You can hear the shutter three times and I also had cases  with obvious alignment issues when shooting hand-held with too long exposure times.

@luator - interesting stuff. Sounds like the .RW2 isn't what some (including me) would think of as a RAW file, but a container for three. What happens if you try to view it in a third party RAW editor? Do you see anything and, if so, does it look like one of the three exposures?

@luator - Apologies : too much Panasonic this week. I'll amend to .RAF (not .RW2).

To third-party editors it looks like a normal raw file of a single exposure, i.e. you can view/process it as if it had been shot in "normal" mode (the embedded preview jpg is the result of the in-camera hdr merge, though).  It seems the two additional exposures are added in a way that doesn't interfere with applications that don't know about them.  As user, you wouldn't notice that anything is different with these files, except maybe for the unusually big file size.
